# Re-Enable button after submit

Tags: asp.net, postback

I'm employing a solution similar to the answer of [OnclientClick and OnClick is not working at the same time ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155048/onclientclick-and-onclick-is-not-working-at-the-same-time)

How this currently works is that a file is generated and returned to the client, however after the file is returned the button should become active again.
so the response contains the file. But the button does not reactivate.

I'm not certain if this can be done.
Any thoughts?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could set the Id mode of the button to static. Then choose a unique Id for the button. Whenever you have verified that the file is successfully transmitted you can call (jquery):

```
$("#idOfSubmitButton").attr("disabled", false);
```

Comment: that would work, except for the part of how to know when the file download dialog box is closed

Comment: just a normal file dialog (save, open, cancel) and it's just a text file. I think the right time would be to check when the dialog was closed.