# ListView ItemCommand Event Not Firing in Firefox

Tags: c#, events, firefox, listview, itemcommand

I am dynamically adding buttons to a listview and using the ItemCommand event to handle the button click event using the CommandName property for the button. It works fine in IE, but when I try in Firefox 5, it is hitting the page load event but not the ItemCommand event. Is there a work-around for Firefox?

Thanks!

> ```
> <asp:ListView ID="lvItems" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="lvItems_ItemDataBound"
>             DataSourceID="odsItems" OnItemCommand="lvItems_ItemCommand" DataKeyNames="ItemID"
>             OnDataBound="lvItems_DataBound" OnPagePropertiesChanging="lvItems_PagePropertiesChanging">
>             <LayoutTemplate>
>                             <div id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
>                             </div>
>             </LayoutTemplate>
>             <ItemTemplate>
>                             <div>
>                                             <asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server">
>                                             </asp:Label>
>                                             <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" CommandName="Add" Text="Add" OnClientClick="this.disabled=true;" />
>                             </div>
>             </ItemTemplate>
>             <EmptyDataTemplate>
>                             No items found for the selected filters. Please try again.<br />
>                             <br />
>             </EmptyDataTemplate>
> </asp:ListView>
>
>
> protected void lvItems_ItemCommand(object sender,ListViewCommandEventArgs e) 
> {
> if (e.CommandName == "Add")
>     {  
>         //code here; 
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: You should show us your code where you're adding the buttons dynamicallyto the ListView and where you databind it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set [UseSubmitBehaviour](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.usesubmitbehavior%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) to `false`, because disabling a button on clientside will cancel the browsers submit. By the way, in IE  it's exactly the same.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" CommandName="Add" Text="Add"
   UseSubmitBehavior="false" OnClientClick="this.disabled='true';" />
```

On this way ASP.NET will append the necessary client-script to postback at the end of your script:

```
__doPostBack('btnAdd','')
```

- http://encosia.com/disable-a-button-control-during-postback/
- [OnclientClick and OnClick is not working at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155048/onclientclick-and-onclick-is-not-working-at-the-same-time/2155126#2155126)