# How to disable a button with OnClientClick event and enable OnClick event and run Server side Code?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms

How to disable a button with OnClientClick event and execute serverside code simultaneously with OnClick funtion? I tried and dod not work. Can someone please help me?

```js
function disableButton(SaveDetailsButton) {
  var btn = document.getElementById("<%=SaveDetailsButton.ClientID %>").removeAttribute('disabled');
  btn.enabled = false;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <asp:Button ID="SaveDetailsButton" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-success btn-lg" BackColor="#2b5797" ForeColor="White" Font-Names="Georgia" Text="Save Details" OnClick="SaveDetailsButton_Click" OnClientClick="javascript:disableButton(this.id);" />
</div>
```

Comment: By *simultaneously* do you mean humbly (I mean no order, no conditions etc.) triggering both `OnClientClick` and `OnClick`. If so, this may help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/21550410/4636715

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't you be adding disable attribute

```
document.getElementById("<%=SaveDetailsButton.ClientID %>").setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
```