# Default button fired instead of focused button in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, button, default

Aspx page contains a panel having a default button called `btnFilter`. Panel having another button `btnReset`. When my focus is inside panel & I press enter its fires `btnFilter` click event that is OK. But first I put focus on reset button & then press enter it fires `btnFilter` click event instead of firing `btnReset` click event.

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: something wrong with eventhandler ..

Comment: @matzone When you press the enter it will always call click event of your default button.

Comment: You have to show the code ..

Comment: Just look bellow link

[Default button not working in asp.net panel][1]

[How to set the default button in content page using asp.net?][2]

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11923457/default-button-not-working-in-asp-net-panel
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12263011/how-to-set-the-default-button-in-content-page-using-asp-net