# Page.Form.DefaultButton doesn't work in a page with no input

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

It is me or `Page.Form.DefaultButton` doesn't seem to work in a page with no input ? I tried looking for this information but found nothing. Cause right now I am on a page where I set the default button and this doesn't work at all.

Comment: Hello. Where is your default button? Is in a usercontrol or something?

Comment: Yes. It is in an user control.

Comment: I found the answer to that question.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11923457/default-button-not-working-in-asp-net-panel

Answer (score 0):

I seem to recall this is a known issue.

You can also set a DefaultButton on an `<asp:Panel>` - is it practical for you to do this instead?

Actually thinking about it further I think if you add a hidden input on the page it would also fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the default button to the specific panel or content.

Try that an let me know....