# Not able to run javascript in content page while using Masterpage

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

**I am not able to run progressbar code in asp.net on button click,while using contentpage/masterpage.

I have checked code without masterpage it'sworking cool..but getting problem while using
masterpage.
What is the problem i am not able to figure out??**

```
 <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Admin.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="UploadStudentDB.aspx.cs" Inherits="Admin_UploadStudentDB" %>

        <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="Contentplaceholder2" Runat="Server">
          <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            var size = 2;
            var id = 0;

            function ProgressBar() {
                if (document.getElementById('<%=txtFilePath.ClientID %>').value != "") 
                {
                    document.getElementById("divProgress").style.display = "block";
                    document.getElementById("divUpload").style.display = "block";
                    id = setInterval("progress()", 20);
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    alert("Select a file to upload");
                    return false;
                }
            }

            function progress() {
                size = size + 1;
                if (size > 299) {
                    clearTimeout(id);
                }
                document.getElementById("divProgress").style.width = size + "pt";
                document.getElementById("<%=lblPercentage.ClientID %>").
                        firstChild.data = parseInt(size / 3) + "%";
            }

        </script>
        <body>
            <div id="divUpload" style="display:none">
                                 <div style="width:300pt;text-align:center;">Uploading...</div>
                                  <div style="width:300pt;height:20px; border:solid 1pt gray">
                                  <div id="divProgress" runat="server" 
                     style="width: 1pt; height: 20px; background-color:Gray;display:none">
                                   </div>
                                     </div>
                      <div style="width:300pt;text-align:center;">
                         <asp:Label ID="lblPercentage" runat="server" 
                         Text="Label"></asp:Label></div>
                                 </div>

         <div align="center">
            <table style="width: 100%; background-color:Silver"  border="1">
                        <tbody align="center">
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="XX-Large" 
                Text="Please Select Excel File Containg Student Details..." ForeColor="White" 
                Font-Underline="True"></asp:Label>


                            </td>
                        </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                         <div style="background: url(hline.gif) repeat-x bottom #F2F2F2;padding: 8px 5px;border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;">
                                    <asp:FileUpload ID="txtFilePath" runat="server"></asp:FileUpload>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                    <asp:Button 
                                        ID="btnUpload" runat="server" Text="Upload" OnClientClick="return ProgressBar();" onclick="btnUpload_Click"  />
                                    <br />
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" Visible="False" Font-Bold="True" 
                                        ForeColor="#009933" Font-Size="Large"></asp:Label>
                                </div>



                                </td>
                            </tr>
    <table>
    </div>
```

Comment: Side note...you shouldn't interperse two languages like that.   Write all your asp vars to a single Json object and read from that.

Comment: This might be related http://stackoverflow.com/q/2155048/1741542

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. If you find an answer helpful, you can upvote it. If an answer solves your question, please accept it. See also [How do I ask questions here?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's the rogue `body` tag just after the closing `script` tag.