# Using onsubmit to disable a button loses the button key / value in POST

Tags: javascript, forms, post

I am trying to prevent a form's save button from being clicked twice. When I set `onsubmit='save.disabled=true'` in the form's tag, the button is disabled when submitted but the POST data no longer contains the "Save" key and value. Since I have multiple buttons on the form, I need to know which one was clicked. Is there another way to disable the save button without this side effect?

```
<form method='post' action='dosomething.php?' enctype='multipart/form-data' onsubmit='save.disabled=true'>
    ... input types & Other buttons ...
    <input type='submit' name='save' value='Save'>
</form>
```

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/2155126/87956

Comment: It seems this answer is asp specific. But it did give me the idea that, instead of changing the button's value, would it work to change the button's 'name' property each time it is clicked, so that I can recognize whether it is Save, Save1, Save11...

Comment: Why just don't hide the button instead disabling it?

Comment: Yes that works. If there is no better way to do it. As I don't like disappearing buttons, I probably will create a new disabled fake button to display in its place. If there is no better solution, create a post for this and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you assign another variable the value of the button you clicked before disabling? Something along the lines of:

```
$('#submit').click(function () {
    $('#form').append("<input type='hidden' name='" + $(this).attr('name') + "' value='"+
                     $(this).attr('value')+ "' />");
    $(this).attr("disabled", true);
    $('#form').submit();
    });
```

Comment: Why you are sure he uses jQuery?

Comment: I don't use jQuery, but I was able to take the idea and translate it, I used createElement() and set all the properties. Great idea. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't really need jquery, this can be done in core is.  i was just giving an example.

Answer (score 0):

Why just don't hide the button. When you disable form element, it doesn't appear in $_POST.

```
<form method='post' action='dosomething.php?' enctype='multipart/form-data' onsubmit='save.style["visibility"] = "hidden"'>
        ... input types & Other buttons ...
        <input type='submit' name='save' value='Save'>
    </form>
```

Comment: I need the save button to appear in $_POST so I know which button was pressed.