# onclick not working if I add Onclient() on asp button

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to add a confirmation message on button click , but `btnUpdateEmail_Click` not working now.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" UseSubmitBehavior="false" 
            Text="Update Import Email" ValidationGroup="groupValidation" 
            OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to update 
            Import Email?');" OnClick="btnUpdateEmail_Click"   
            CssClass="btn-danger" Height="46px" Width="237px" 
            Font-Bold="true" />
```

Comment: Your provided code is working fine (I tested by adding a new aspx page in my web app and the confirmation is shown)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OnclientClick and OnClick is not working at the same time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155048/onclientclick-and-onclick-is-not-working-at-the-same-time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to only change the value of UseSubmitBehavior from false to true.

I hope it will resolve your problem.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" UseSubmitBehavior="true" Text="Update Import Email" ValidationGroup="groupValidation" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to update Import Email?');" OnClick="btnUpdateEmail_Click"   CssClass="btn-danger" Height="46px" Width="237px" Font-Bold="true" />
```

Comment: UseSubmitBehavior="false" What exactly this will do

Comment: By default asp button behavior is to post data on server (submit behavior) but if you want to disable this behavior and make it only perform client side work then you can use UseSubmitBehavior="false"

You can achieve this thing from another way using jquery ajax method where your button call a client side java-script function and after that you use ajax call to invoke server side method. But that is too lengthy code.

Comment: I just remove UseSubmitBehavior="true" and my code is working as by default its value is true

Answer (score 1):

Using **UseSubmitBehavior="true"** nearly did the trick. Be sure to have your `OnClientClick` call set up correctly:

Code was using `OnClientClick="return Validate();"` which is incorrect. It should just be

```
<asp:Button ID="keyword" runat="server" Text="Search" TabIndex="1" 
OnClick="keywordSearch_Click" OnClientClick="if (!Validate()) { return false;};" />
```

If it is set up incorrectly, the `OnClick` function will not fire.

Also [click here](http://nileshmandekar.blogspot.com/2012/04/aspbutton-onclientclick-and-onclick-not.html), for more.

Also you can find, [onclientclick-and-onclick-is-not-working-at-the-same-time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155048/onclientclick-and-onclick-is-not-working-at-the-same-time).