# Why won't the ASP.NET Webform LinkButton in my MVC project invoke its code-behind OnClick event handler?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, webforms, linkbutton

I have a previously operational webforms project I had to include in a preexistent MVC-based solution and in it there's a LinkButton control inside a form that is now only partially working; its JavaScript event handler works perfectly fine (referenced below by OnClientClick) but the C# code-behind (lnkSubmit_Click) isn't being invoked! Why not?

My LinkButton's inside Pay.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Pay.aspx.cs" Inherits="PayUp.Pay" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" %> 

<form id="form1" runat="server" onsubmit="return validateForm();" defaultbutton="lnkSubmit" action="~/Views/Home/Pay.aspx" method="post" >

    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <div align="center">

       <script type="text/javascript">
          window.onload = function () {
              hideFields();
          };
       </script>

       <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" id="PendingPayments1">
           <ContentTemplate>

               <!-- Valid form controls, blah blah.... -->

           </ContentTemplate>
       </asp:UpdatePanel>

       <asp:Label ID="labelPayPlan" runat="server" Text="Pay Plan">    
       </asp:Label>

       <asp:HiddenField ID="hiddenPDFForm" Value="false" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />

       <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" id="PaymentInformation1">
           <ContentTemplate>
               <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkSubmit" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" OnClientClick="javascript: document.getElementById('hiddenPDFForm').value = 'false';"
                   CssClass="button" onclick="lnkSubmit_Click" onserverclick="lnkSubmit_Click" ClientIDMode="Static">Pay Up!<img alt='Pay Up!' src='images/pay.gif' style='border:0px; margin-left:6px;' />
               </asp:LinkButton>
           </ContentTemplate>
       </asp:UpdatePanel>
</form >
```

The code-behind does exist inside Pay.aspx.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Configuration;
using SupportingMVCProject;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace PayUp
{
    public partial class Pay : System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<SupportingMVCProject.Account>
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // The code in this event handler runs just fine when I start the project!
            // This code successfully receives and correctly parses my URL parameters (QN, PN, AC).
        }

        protected void lnkSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // The code in this event handler never gets to run!
        }
    }
}
```

My RouteConfig.cs looks like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace MainMVCProject
{
    public static class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{WebForm}.aspx/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute("PayUpIndex", "SupportingMVCProject/PayUp",
               new { controller = "PayUp", action = "Index" }
               );

            // Other valid preexisting MVC routes...
            // blah, blah
        }
    }
}
```

The PayUpController.cs PayUpIndex route identified above looks like the following, and it does run:

```
    public ActionResult Index(string QN, string PN, string AC)
    {

        string result = "";
        if (!AccessValidation(PN, out result))
        {
            return RedirectToAction(result);
        }

        // blah blah

        ViewData["message"] = "QN=" + QN + "PN=" + PN + "AC=" + AC;

        return this.View("~/Views/PayUp/Pay.aspx");
    }
```

My start URL is http://localhost:3835/SupportingMVCProject/PayUp?QN=ABC-1234567&PN=ABC1234567&AC=123456789. It launches the page just fine and all controls are interactive, all except my "Pay Up!" button (lnkSubmit). Why is lnkSubmit_Click inside Pay.aspx.cs not being invoked?

Your insight is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I got further by removing the following attributes from the <form> tag in Pay.aspx: action="~/Views/Home/Pay.aspx" method="post".  Now clicking the button at least does invoke some code-behind, just not the lnkSubmit_Click eventhandler I wish! Instead, the Index function inside PayUpCOntroller.cs is what's being executed.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure I have read somewhere that if you use OnClientClick then server side code will not run unless you make some changes

Check out the below link

[OnclientClick and OnClick is not working at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155048/onclientclick-and-onclick-is-not-working-at-the-same-time)

Comment: Well, the funny thing is everything works perfectly for that previously operational webforms project when it stands on its own; it's when I stick it inside the MVC solution and try to integrate it there that I lose the lnkSubmit_Click button functionality. I tried the solution given in the link you provided and it didn't improve my situation. The JavaScript code still runs client-side, but the server-side code-behind lnkSubmit_Click eventhandler is never invoked. The old Page_Load eventhandler works! Why won't this lnkSubmit_Click?